# Array filtering in nested object using ramda

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

Let's assume that we have the following object:

```js
const sample = {
  foo: {
    tags: [
      'aaa', 'bbb'
    ],
    a: 1,
    b: 10
  },
  bar: {
    tags: [
      'ccc', 'ddd'
    ],
    a: 11,
    b: 100
  }
}
```

How can one remove a specific tag value from object `sample` using ramda?
I have done this

```js
/// Remove tag named 'aaa'
R.map(v => R.assoc('tags', R.without('aaa', v.tags), v), sample)
```

which achieves the desired result but how can I eliminate the lamda (and the closure created) inside map ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`evolve`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#evolve) instead of [`assoc`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#assoc). `assoc` expects a property and plain value to set on provided object, whereas `evolves` expects a property and function producing the new value (although in a slightly other syntax).

```
R.map(R.evolve({tags: R.without('aaa')}), sample)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can [R.evolve](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#evolve) each object, and use R.without to transform the value of `tags`:

```js
const { map, evolve, without } = R

const fn = map(evolve({
  tags: without('aaa')
}))

const sample = {"foo":{"tags":["aaa","bbb"],"a":1,"b":10},"bar":{"tags":["ccc","ddd"],"a":11,"b":100}}

const result = fn(sample)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.0/ramda.js"></script>
```